# How can I manually configure a network drive mapping in Windows 3.11?

Tags: network-shares, windows-3.1

### background

We have a single Windows 3.11 computer on our network. Users have not been able to authenticate ever since we upgraded our domain controllers to Windows Server 2008 R2 and disabled support for LANMAN hashes.

This computer only needs access to a single file location. To get around our authentication problem, we disabled all security to the network share in question. All has been working fine ever since.

### problem

The path to this folder has changed, so we need to modify the drive mapping within Windows 3.11. Unfortunately, it seems that any modifications of drive mappings through the command-line interface or GUI require user authentication. Each of the following commands triggers a logon prompt, which fails.

```
NET USE /PERSISTENT:LIST
NET USE O: /DELETE /YES
NET USE O: \\server\win311 ? /PERSIST:YES
```

I know that if I could only force the drive mapping configuration it would work just fine. Unfortunately, it seems that `NET USE` isn't going to work for me.

I've checked through `system.ini`, `win.ini` etc. From what I've found online Windows may store these configurations in `wfwsys.cfg`, but this is a binary file.

Does anyone know of a way to get around `NET USE` prompting me for a password?

### update

- According too [KB90210](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/90210), drive mapping information is stored in a file named `connect.dat`. This file is encrypted to prevent people from modifying it by hand.
- The requirement to log on to our domain is likely being caused from left over configurations in the `system.ini` or `win.ini` files. If the computer could be placed in peer-to-peer workgroup mode, we would probably be able to set up this drive mapping.
- We settled on creating a file share from the Windows 3.11 box. This computer cannot access remote resources, but other computers on the network can access its shares.

Comment: +1 for still using Win 3.11, maybe you'll need the extra points to start a bounty...

Comment: We'll need to bring in some AD gurus. This needs to be sent to Server Fault.

Comment: **Disable UAC.** *Oh wait...* Why are you still on Windows 3.1? @surfasb: **[Don't. Migrate. Crap.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446)**

Comment: @surfasb I debated over which site to post this question on. Were I asking how to get this computer to authenticate, then ServerFault would definately be the proper place.This is one of those situations where Windows prompts for a password when none should be needed.

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Exchange**. Please note that questions like these are too localized and there is no point in solving such an extraordinarily narrow situation: `This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.` If you disagree, feel free to start a [meta](http://meta.superuser.com/) question for clarification.

Comment: @TomWijsman You are in disagreement with Jeff Atwood on the value of specific questions. Read [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/procrastination-and-the-bikeshed-effect.html) blog entry.

Comment: Irrelevant, does not proof disagreement. Now, can *you* tell me the value?

Comment: @Tom "We've struggled with this on Stack Overflow, too. The broad soft questions tend to get much more interest and attention than the **narrow, technical** coding **questions that we originally intended the site for**."

Anyway, I won't be commenting on this further.

Comment: Can I ask, out of curiosity more than anything else, Why do you have a Windows 3.1 machine still? This is not an answer, but, as I am guessing this isn't on a domain, have you tried other solutions such as FTP, or even Samba on a new server (can be a very small virtual server somewhere) that gets files from the 2k8 box and has it's own share with lower security, and just syncs the two :/ ... I hope you do find an answer though!

Comment: Since you've disabled all security to the share, you might try giving it a dummy username and password. Something like NET USE O: \\server\win311 /user:foobar dummypassword.

Comment: @BillP3rd This likely would work if I could get the computer to stop prompting for domain log on. Years ago it had access to the domain before we disabled support for LANMAN hashes. I've had success sharing files _from_ this computer, so the problem is effectively solved. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @William Thanks for the advice. Using FTP or a file server with reduced security sitting in the middle sound like they might work. I ended up getting around this problem by sharing files in the other direction. Other computers on our network are able to see folders shared from Win3.11.

Comment: A quick google didn't turn anything up for me, but if you can find an old copy of USE.EXE, the basic-authentication version from MS Lan Manager (I think it was version 2.x?), that *might* be able to do the trick for you.

Comment: My GOD, why are you guys even still using a windows 3.1 computer on your network?! Thats RIDICULOUS!